# How to load the correct data from a select, based on the object value

Tags: php, object, select, foreach, compare

Here's a generic foreach loop:

```
<label>Type:</label>
<select name="postTypeArray">
  <?php foreach ($postTypeArray as $thePostType) : ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $thePostType ?>"><?php echo $thePostType ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select><br/><br/>
```

When the page loads the postType, it’s either a comment, an image, or a video. This is loaded from a database and stored in the postType object. The problem is, when loading the page, the selected postType is always showing as a comment object, which is the first value in the $postTypeArray, and when I use `selected = "selected"` the selected value retrieved is always video, which is the last value in the $postTypeArray.

I have looked at other answers, tried if statements inside the foreach, used key value array, and etc. but have not found a solution yet.

Comment: in option tag, I think you need selected="selected" and not value="selected"

Comment: What variable name holds the value of what it should select?

Comment: @KarloKokkak sorry I meant to say selected="selected"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you hold your values for the current item in `$post['type']`.

You then use a `selected` attribute to select the value.

```
<label>Type:</label>
<select name="postTypeArray">
<?php foreach ($postTypeArray as $thePostType) : ?>
  <option value="<?= $thePostType ?>"<?= (isset($post['type']) && $post['type'] === $thePostType ? ' selected' : '')?>><?= $thePostType ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you! your answer is correct, but do mind elaborating a bit more about how **$post['type'] === $thePostType ? ' selected' : ''** works? Thanks

Comment: Its like an if/else statement its called a ternary, so it like doing the following but much cleaner. `if (isset($post['type']) && $post['type'] === $thePostType) { echo ' selected'; } else { echo ''; }`, though the else is not required its equivalent.

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary